# The cube cannot be browsed. Verify that the cube has been deployed and processed. (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: ssas

I have an SSAS cube under SSAS 2008 , the cube is programmed to process once a week on sunday via sql server agent that runs and ssis job to process the cube
every thing worked fine until last monday i tried to open the cube and i had the "The cube cannot be browsed. Verify that the cube has been deployed and processed. (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)" error i verified the sql server agent job it ran on sunday and didnt show any error

any ideas please?

Comment: What is a processing type via SSIS package? Is it a fixed "ProcessFull" XMLA command for the entire cube? Or list of dimensions with "ProcessUpdate" + measure groups (or several partitions) to process? Pls add XMLA processing code here if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cube was processed and you still get this error when browsing the cube, maybe check if you are connecting as a specific Role and if so then check if the role has read access to the cube. You do that by opening the specific role, choose cubes and change access to read instead of None

Answer (score 1):

I was also not able to browse cube using SSMS because of my SQL server browser service was stuck. I have restarted the same and now I am able to browse the cube.

Please refer below:

[image]